# re.match() with fixed pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, fixed

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

I'd like to use `pattern` as a fixed string instead of a regex. But I don't see such option to enable this. In `grep`, this is basically `-F`.

Is there a way to do so with the `re` module in python?

Comment: Use `re.escape()` to escape all the special characters and treat them literally.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `re` module? There are string methods that do most of the same things, e.g. `re.sub` is like `str.replace`